# HAR file generated using SauceREST API doesn't contain all requests like network logs from chrome developers tool

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, har

I have a HAR log file downloaded for particular url from SauceLabs through automated test. I open the same url manually and look at the network logs from the chrome developers tool. When I compare requests in these two places, some of the domains that exist in manual network logs do not exist in the har file downloaded from Saucelabs. The domain that I am looking for is fls.doubleclick.net which is related to google tag manager that only exist in network logs manually but not in HAR logs downloaded from Saucelabs. How is .har file different from network logs generated in the dev tool? Isn't it the same? I analyzed the file properly and it doesn't look itsbecause of wait issue.

Comment: Can you share example if possible? Also you have already asked this question. Please modify the already existing question instead of ask a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait until all network logs in generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58536303/how-to-wait-until-all-network-logs-in-generated)